# BeagleBone Black display

Tags: beaglebone-black

I am trying to get the Nokia 5110 screen up and running on BeagleBone Black rev b. I am using...

- Ken Keller's BeagleBone [Nokia 5110 LCD Bonescript library](https://github.com/kkeller/Nokia5110)
- An Adafruit recycled [Nokia 5110/3310 monochrome LCD](https://www.adafruit.com/products/338)

When I hook all pins up and run the test program below, it doesn't output anything on the screen. I tested all the pins with a voltmeter and got these readings:
- VCC = 3.373V Constant
- RST = 1.63V Constant
- CS = Sits at .001V when program runs, but has a few pulses up to .040V 
- D/C = 3.3V Constant
- DIN = fluctuates between 0-.3xx (so assuming it is sending data)
- CLK = fluctuates as well

Code:

```
var lcd = require('./LCD_5110.js');
var b = require('bonescript');
var timeout = 0;
var inverseIndex;

//
//  Must define the following outputs to use LCD_5110.js
//
lcd.PIN_SDIN = "P9_21";
lcd.PIN_SCLK = "P9_22";
lcd.PIN_SCE = "P9_23";
lcd.PIN_DC = "P9_24";
lcd.PIN_RESET = "P9_25";

lcd.setup();
setTimeout(loop, 5);

function loop() {
// test bitmap write
lcd.clear();
lcd.bitmap(beagle);

inverseIndex = 0;
setTimeout(loop0, 1000*timeout);
}

function loop0() {
// test inverse video
if(inverseIndex % 2) {
    lcd.inverse(lcd.LCD_INVERSE);
} else {
    lcd.inverse(lcd.LCD_NORMAL);
}

inverseIndex++;

if(inverseIndex < 19) {
    setTimeout(loop0, 50*timeout);
} else {
    setTimeout(loop1, 50*timeout);
}
}

function loop1() {
// test normal character write
lcd.clear();
for ( index = 0x41 ; index < 0x7b ; index++)
    lcd.character(String.fromCharCode(index));

setTimeout(loop2, 2000*timeout);
}

function loop2() {
// test bitmap and string write
lcd.clear();
lcd.bitmap(world_map);

setTimeout(loop3, 1000*timeout);
}
```

etc.

Comment: RST looks low to me - what is it connected to?

Comment: RST is connected to pin 9_25, it is reading a constant 1.629V

Comment: I'd expect 3.3V - maybe you have a damaged pin or the pin is used by something else.  Try using a different pin.

Comment: I did use a different pin which showed a voltage of 3.3V. But  there was still nothing displayed on the screen. It appears the program was written for the BeagleBone, not the BeagleBone Black, but after checking the naming on the pins they are essentially the same.

Comment: Something must be different running this on BBB

Comment: I;m still waiting for the new BBBs to come into stock so I can buy one (been holding out for the Rev C).  I can't help much more for now I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the help either way, it turns out that to write to this screen using the library i've chosen, you need to first disable the virtual HDMI cape on the board. That also opens up the UARTs (Im not 100% confident that is exactly right). Any way i have it working now.

Answer (score 1):

Found out how to do it, here is the code

```
/*This script writes variable headers and their values to a
/ Nokia 5110 screen on the BBB. The virtual HDMI cape must be disabled for
/ this to occur, and the LCD_5110.js file must be placed in the same directory.
/ verified to work with BBB REV C, use pins
/
/ lcd.PIN_SCLK = "P8_38";
/ lcd.PIN_SDIN = "P8_37";
/ lcd.PIN_DC = "P8_39";
/ lcd.PIN_SCE = "P8_41";
/ lcd.PIN_RESET = "P8_43";
/credit to kkeller's work @ github.com/kkeller/Nokia5110 
*/

var lcd = require('./LCD_5110.js');

lcd.PIN_SCLK = "P8_38";
lcd.PIN_SDIN = "P8_37";
lcd.PIN_DC = "P8_39";
lcd.PIN_SCE = "P8_41";
lcd.PIN_RESET = "P8_43";


var strokeInterval = 2300;
var voltage = 9;
var error = 'none';




lcd.setup();
lcd.gotoXY(0,0);
lcd.string('            CYCLES: '+strokeInterval);
lcd.clear();

lcd.gotoXY(0,0);
lcd.string('            VOLTAGE: '+ voltage);
lcd.clear();

lcd.gotoXY(0,0);
lcd.string('            ERRORS: '+ error);
lcd.clear();

lcd.string('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the lcd.PIN_RESET = "P9_25"; to lcd.PIN_RESET = "P9_26"; in both software and hardware.
The pin "P9_25" is used by the BBB for other purpose.

Regards,
Abhishek.